# .where() by populated fields

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

**I want to find the closest workers by his location which have a specific skill.**

Location schema:

```
var schema = Schema({
    name: String,
    type: String, // home | latest
    user: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
    address: String,
    position: {
        type: {type: String, default: 'Point'},
        coordinates: [Number]
    },
    status: String // active | inactive
}, {collection: 'locations'});
```

Worker schema:

```
var schema = Schema({
    username: String,
    password: String,
    firstName: {type: String, default: ''},
    middleName: {type: String, default: ''},
    lastName: {type: String, default: ''},
    role: {type: String, default: 'user'}, // admin | user | worker
    skills: [{
        object: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Skill'},
        slug: String, // Should remove in the future
        ratePerHour: Number,
        status: {type: String, default: 'active'} // active | inactive
    }],
    locations: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Location'}]
}, {collection: 'users'});
```

Skill schema:

```
var schema = Schema({
    name: String,
    slug: String,
    users: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'}],
    isFeatured: Boolean,
    minRatePerHour: Number,
    maxRatePerHour: Number,
    status: String // active | inactive | deleted
}, {collection: 'skills'});
```

Bellow is my query but `.where()` does not work with populated field.

```
Location
    .find({
        'position': {
            $near: {
                $geometry: {type: 'Point', coordinates: [lat, lng]},
                $minDistance: 0,
                $maxDistance: 20000
            }
        }
    })
    .populate('user')
    .deepPopulate('user.skills.object')
    .where({'user.skills': {$elemMatch: {'object.slug': 'cleaning'}}})
    .limit(5)
    .exec(callback);
```

Am I doing wrong with these schemas? Should I use embed document rather than ID reference?
Is there any way else to query?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use special properties for `populate` as described here: [Query conditions and other options](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)

So I think you can get your results with something like this:

```
Location
.find({
  'position': {
    $near: {
      $geometry: {
        type: 'Point',
        coordinates: [lat, lng]
      },
      $minDistance: 0,
      $maxDistance: 20000
    }
  }
})
.populate({
  path: 'user',
  match: {
    'skills': {
      $elemMatch: {
        'object.slug': 'cleaning'
      }
    }
  },
  options: {
    limit: 5
  }
})
.deepPopulate('user.skills.object')
.exec(callback);
```

Not tested, keep it only as example.

Comment: `object.slug` only existed after `.deepPopulate()` ... beyond, `object` field contains value of `Skill._id`

Comment: It's only an example you should review and fix it for your needs.

Comment: I tried `match` option in `.populate()` several times but it only affects the object which will be populated. `user` field will be `null` if user does not match during population.